# What condition do I have to specify to run installation sequence during install and uninstall too?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, conditional-statements, installshield, uninstallation

I'd like to use ScheduleReboot Install sequence to run on install and uninstall too. (In Installshield)

What condition do I have to specify for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario pair of "install and uninstall" is somewhat underspecified, so I would probably go with no condition, or the condition `1`. Except you're talking about reboots, which should be avoided whenever possible.

One way to limit it slightly is to avoid running the action during maintenance that does not remove the entire product. If you want that, you should combine the [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368013.aspx) and [install](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368561.aspx) examples and go with something like `REMOVE="ALL" or Not Installed`

Comment: That's correct!  A few minutes ago I figured it out myself tried and works perfect!